# Get 3 random values from a Dictionary (with tuple string[]) without duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following function:

```
private static string[] ReturnAnswers2(string CorrectAnswer, Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string[]>> AnswerWrongDict, string uniqueKey)
{
    //Get wrong answers from Item2 array and placing 1 CorrectAnswer making sure there are is no duplicated CorrectAnswer.
    string[] result = AnswerWrongDict.OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid())
      .Where(n => n.Value.Item2 != null && !n.Value.Item2[0].Equals(CorrectAnswer) && n.Value.Item1 != uniqueKey).Take(3).Select(a => a.Value.Item2[0])
      .Concat(new[] { CorrectAnswer })
      .OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid())
      .ToArray();

    return result;
}
```

The dictionary `AnswerWrongDict` contains:

- First string: Some name desc (no duplicates, Ignored here)
- Second string in tuple: uniqueKey (no
  duplicates)
- Third string[]: array of wrong answers (can be different sizes
  or even null)

What it does it gets 4 answers: 3 random wrong answers and 1 correct.
The wrong answers are inside a string[] in a tuple dictionary.

This works, only issue that i can receive duplicate wrong answers from the third value string[] (a.Value.Item2[0]).

How do i make sure there are no duplicates from the 3 wrong answers?

If I place `Distinct()` after `.OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid())` it will remove duplicates but i can get sometimes 3 answers while I need 4 (because duplicated distincted).

Can't seem to solve this. Help appreciated.

Comment: I think there is a X Y problem.

Comment: Don't use `Guid.NewGuid()` as a source of randomness. It's not. It's only a source of uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks,  what is the alternative?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing duplicates `.Take` records or before selecting random records you can exclude duplicates.

```
AnswerWrongDict.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Distinct().Take(4);
```

Comment: Thanks!, This does the trick by adding: `.Distinct().Take(3)` **AFTER** `.Select(a => a.Value.Item2[0])`

Comment: oh! if you are not sure using `Guid.NewGuid()`, you can generate rendom number between 0 & your listCount.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.Take()` linq expression attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
AnswerWrongDict.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Distinct().Take(3);
```